# How to get index of uiimage subview of uiscrollview

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, uiscrollview

I need to detect selected image of uiimage which is placed inside scrollview.

My code is here:

```
int newscrollviewY = 40;
    for(int i = 0; i<1; i++)
    {
        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, newscrollviewY, 310, 100)];
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        scrollView.delegate=self;
        int imgx = 1;

        for(int img=0; img<[images count]; img++)
        {

            UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imgx,0,100,100)];
            imageView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            imageView1.image = [images objectAtIndex:img];
            imageView1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [imageView1 setNeedsDisplay];
            [imageView1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [imageView1 setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
            [scrollView addSubview:imageView1];


            imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(imgx,0,100,100);
            [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            imageButton.tag = img;
            [scrollView addSubview:imageButton];
            imgx = imgx + 103;


        }
```

Please help to detect selected image using `imageButton` or something else.

Comment: When your button gets tap from user at that time you should keep track of selected image from tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your selector with `buttonClicked:` 
be Sure that you are adding "**:**" after selector method. follow or replace the code below:

```
[imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then Add the selector definantion in .m file

```
- (void) buttonClicked: (id) sender
{
    // here you can get the tag of button.

    NSInteger tag = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;

    // do your implementation after this
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue. Enjoy Coding..!!

Comment: Thankyou for simply answer.

Comment: My Pleasure...Enjoy coding..!!:)

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I tried to remedy the situation. This was a great answer.. +1

Answer (score 0):

They way you have set it up the tag of the 'button' is already the number of the image in your array of images. So all you need to do is get the tag from the 'button'.

Make sure the button clicked function retrieves the tag from the sender(id) that you receive.

For example a bit like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UIImage selectedImages = [images objectForKey: [button tag]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As par you question if you are using `UIImageview` you have to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` that same like Button. you just need to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` like:-

```
    for(int img=0; img<[images count]; img++)
    {

        UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imgx,0,100,100)];
        imageView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *frameTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(frameTapGesture:)];
        frameTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;

        imageView1.image = [images objectAtIndex:img];
        imageView1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [imageView1 setNeedsDisplay];
        [imageView1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [imageView1 setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
         imageView1.tag=img;
        [_imgView addGestureRecognizer:frameTapGesture];
        [scrollView addSubview:imageView1];

    }.

- (void)frameTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UIView *view = sender.view; //cast pointer to the derived class if needed
    NSLog(@"%d", view.tag);
}
```

Reduce your code There are No need to add Button with same Frame of `ImageView` For getting Click Event or you can also set Image of `UIButton` for you want to like use UIBUtton then remove UIImageview Code else you simply use `UITapGestureRecognizer` with getting click event using `- (void)frameTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender`

Comment: You are assuming he does not need the button clicked action for anything else. But yes, also a valid solution.

Comment: @ophychius humm but both are not requered with same frame use put code UIImageview as well as Button. i assume that use only add Button for getting Button Click event and get Image but we are also set Image of Button so there is No need of Imageview set else simply use `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead of using Button that is useless code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
for(int img=0; img<[images count]; img++)
    {
        imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(imgx,0,100,100);
        [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        imageButton.tag = img;
        [scrollView addSubview:imageButton];
        imgx = imgx + 103;


    }
- (void) buttonClicked: (id) sender
{
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   UIImage selectedImage = button.currentImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set button target

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

// get Button Action

```
-(void) buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
 NSLog(@"%dl",sender.tag);
// do your implementation after this
}
```